# Select maximum version from collection with LINQ in EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity

I'm struggling to filter an array of results down by TOP version number. The following gives me all ProductApprover objects and distinct Version info:

```
foreach (ModelLib.ProductApprover app in products)
        {
            if(distinct.Where(p => p.Product.ID == app.Product.ID && p.Version == app.Version).FirstOrDefault() == null)
                distinct.Add(app);
        }
```

I then want to do a query that follows that selects the top version numbered products ONLY. Can anybody assist me in this endeavour please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Top versions for each product:

```
var topVersions = products
    .GroupBy(arg => arg.ProductId)
    .Select(arg => new { ProductId = arg.Key, TopVersion = arg.Max(x => x.Version) })
    .ToList();
```

or products that have the top version:

```
var productsThatHaveTheTopVersion = products
    .Where(arg => arg.Version == products.Max(arg.Version))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (ModelLib.ProductApprover app in products)
{
   if(distinct.Where(p => p.Product.ID == app.Product.ID)
       .OrderByDescending(p=>p.Version)
       .FirstOrDefault( p=>p.Version == app.Version) != null)
            distinct.Add(app);
}
```